# Ionic 5 Capacitor with Microsoft SSO

Tags: ionic-framework, azure-ad-msal, capacitor, msal-angular

I am trying to implement Microsoft SSO with Ionic 5 but am having no luck. I have tried using [@azure/msal-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular) [@azure/msal-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser) method but this seems to only work in web. Has anyone tried to implement this recently?

Here is the error I'm getting in XCODE

```
[error] - Big ERROR OCCURED! {​​​​​​​​"errorCode":"popup_window_error","errorMessage":"Error opening popup window. This can happen if you are using IE or if popups are blocked in the browser. Details: BrowserAuthError: empty_window_error: window.open returned null or undefined window object.","subError":"","name":"BrowserAuthError"}​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: You must be using the loginPopup, which will give a login page in page, this might not be supported in natively xcode/ios. Instead try the loginRedirect

Comment: these libraries are for web implementations, not mobile apps

Comment: @VikrantSingh

I've tried loginRedirect which works on web and not mobile app

Comment: But i think as @Carlos.V mentioned probably need to find a Cap 3.0 plugin that does this job for mobile apps.

Comment: @VinnyP. there are special steps to make it work on mobile, like this https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-android

Comment: is there alternative plugin that we can use to connect to azure ad aside from msal? because I heard MSAL is not supporting mobile applications. their MSAL.js is only for WEB